# undefined method `each_with_index' for :relationship_status:Symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, enums

I am using `_prefix` for same enums.

**My Model**

```
enum relationship_status: [:All,:Married, :Single, :Engaged, :Divorced, :Widowed, :Separated, :Complicated], _prefix: :relationship_status
enum gender: [:All,:Male, :Female], _prefix: :gender
enum qualification: [:All,:Uneducated,:Matric, :Inter, :Graduation, :Masters, :PHD], _prefix: :qualification
```

It gives an error

```
undefined method `each_with_index' for :relationship_status:Symbol
```

How I fix it?

Comment: How rails version you use? AFAIK it was introduced in rails 5.

Comment: I am using rails 4.....

Comment: In rails 4 there's not option `_prefix` available and this causes this error.